# Javascript Event listener when hitting the TAB key

Tags: javascript

i have a table that containes formulas and the table would update everytime the button update is being clicked this works fine however i wanted the table to be updated automatically everytime the tab button is being clicked so i added an event listener this is my code:

```
<script>
    function changeActionUpdate() {
        document.getElementById("vehicleform").action = '{{url_for("salaries.salaries_update")}}';
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
        var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
        if (code === 9) {  
            changeActionUpdate();
            /*alert("Hello Tab key")*/
        }
    });

</script>
```

i noticed it's not updating so i added the alert to check if my function worked and it did however it keeps ignoring the changeActionUpdate() function please note that the changeActionUpdate() is the one iam using in the update button so i'm 100% sure it works.

salaries_update:

```
@salaries_bp.route('/salaries/update', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def salaries_update():
  """
   Update a collection in the database
  """
x = {}
if request.method == "POST":
    ref = db.company.find_one({"GlobalId": "global"})

    x["Salaries_Header1"] = (int(ref["basic_year"])) 
    x["Salaries_Header2"] = (int(ref["basic_year"]) + 1 )
    x["Salaries_Header3"] = (int(ref["basic_year"]) + 2 )
    x["Salaries_Header4"] = (int(ref["basic_year"]) + 3 )
    x["Salaries_Header5"] = (int(ref["basic_year"]) + 4 ) 

    x = get_form_to_dict(request.form) ... (i'm going to skip the formulas)

    db.salaries.update_one({"GlobalId": "global"}, {"$set": x})
x = db.salaries.find_one({"GlobalId": "global"})
return redirect(url_for('salaries.salaries')) 
return render_template("salaries-wages.html", data=x)
```

Comment: The code you've shown fundamentally works (although it A) uses deprecated properties \[both `keyCode` and `which` are replaced by [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)​] and B) doesn't prevent the default action, so the Tab still gets processed by the browser). Looks to me like you're using some kind of server-side templating for the string used by `changeActionUpdate`. I suspect it works when you use a button because it goes back to the server, but that's a guess. Without more details about the templating mechanism, I'm afraid we can't help you.

Comment: i just updated the question to show the server-side

Comment: So your next step is to make the Tab key trigger your server-side code, apparently.

Comment: Thank you so much so i just added a .submit() and it works fine